# Larastan doesn't resolve aliase of facades

Tags: php, phpstan, laravel-facade

I'm using larastan on a Laravel project.
When I use a facade like `¥Auth::check()` like code below, larastan can't resolve the return type of this method.

```php
function index()
{
  if(¥Auth::check()) { // as mixed
    // ...
  }
}
```

I know it's resolved by adding a use operator with `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` and using `Auth::check()` instead.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

function index()
{
  if(Auth::check()) { // as bool
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is it not recommended to use alias of facades with larastan?
Let me know the best practice if there are some way to use facade alias with larastan.

---

PHP: 8.1
larastan: 2.9.2